# Lack of intellisense on array of structs

Tags: go

In Atom and IntelliJ writing golang, when I have an array of structs and I loop over it in a `range`or have `firstItem = myArray[0]` when I try to interact with that variable the editor doesn't give me properties etc of the struct via intellisense.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the type of myArray? If it isn't []interface{}, then that should work. One thing that could be happening is if myArray's type is defined in another package or source file. Gocode only reads compiled libraries, not raw source code. Try "go install {path to package}" and see if autocomplete lights up.

Comment: Its in another package but a subfolder of my application so is that the same?

Comment: Please file an issue – https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

The answer comes from @vansimke in that I needed to have `go install myapp` executed for GoCode to pick up the heirachy of dependencies so it would give me the intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ it should totally be possible to get the autocompletion to work. I use it daily and I don't have any issues with that. There might be some well hidden edge cases where this happens so if you indeed have problems with it, please open a detailed issue here: https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/new and you should be able to receive more guidance.

Also, it would help to know a bit more about your code layout (paths and so on) and a sample of code that can reproduce the issue.

Hope it helps.